# Postgresql and Java passing one value and using it in multiple places without cross join

Tags: java, postgresql

I have a query I am writing in postgresql.  I am calling this from a java jdbc library using a prepared statement.  I have a date field that I want to pass in to see if any of the relating tables have updated since I last checked.  However I don't know how to have the date fill multiple spots.  Here is what works.

```
WHERE p.last_updated_time > '2015-02-06 11:21:32.064'
          OR p.p_id IN (
              SELECT DISTINCT con.p_id
              FROM enriched.p_con con 
              WHERE con.last_updated_time > '2015-02-06 11:21:32.064'
              )
          OR p.p_id IN (
              SELECT DISTINCT pi.p_id
              FROM enriched.p_ident pi
              WHERE pi.last_updated_time > '2015-02-06 11:21:32.064'
              )
          OR p.p_id IN (
              SELECT DISTINCT pp.p_id
              FROM enriched.p_p pp
              WHERE pp.last_updated_time > '2015-02-06 11:21:32.064'
              )
          OR p.p_id IN (
              SELECT DISTINCT prov.p_id
              FROM enriched.p_prov prov
              WHERE prov.last_updated_time > '2015-02-06 11:21:32.064'
              )
```

However when I change it to use the prepared statement to the following I get an error.

```
WHERE p.last_updated_time > ?
      OR p.p_id IN (
      SELECT DISTINCT con.p_id
      FROM enriched.p_con con
      WHERE con.last_updated_time > ?
      )
      OR p.p_id IN (
      SELECT DISTINCT pi.p_id
      FROM enriched.p_ident pi
      WHERE pi.last_updated_time > ?
      )
      OR p.p_id IN (
      SELECT DISTINCT pp.p_id
      FROM enriched.p_p pp
      WHERE pp.last_updated_time > ?
      )
      OR p.p_id IN (
      SELECT DISTINCT prov.p_id
      FROM enriched.p_prov prov
      WHERE prov.last_updated_time > ?
      )
```

I tried using a cross join which works but takes my query time from 45 seconds to several days.

```
CROSS JOIN (SELECT TO_DATE(?, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS.MS') last_crawl_date) ld
```

Any thoughts?  This seems like a simple problem to fix but I just can't seem to see it.

Answer (score 0):

You have 5 ? in your prepared statement SQL, so you'll need to set the date five times.

```
statement.setDate(1, yourDate);
statement.setDate(2, yourDate);
statement.setDate(3, yourDate);
statement.setDate(4, yourDate);
statement.setDate(5, yourDate);
```

Comment: I was hoping to avoid that.  If there is no other way then I can do that it just will require a fair amount of code re-work.